# EF Designer (DB first) very slow and not updating

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF db-first and I have a quite complex model in the DB, including table-returning inline-functions.

EF designer "Update Model from database" is not working when those functions are updated. (note: it gives me a mapping error on the column that I have updated in the IF)

I have to drop and recreate the whole model every time I update those parts. Moreover the overall process is very slow.

Do you have any suggestion on this problem or to speed-up things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. The EF designer is bad. It also does not handle updates at all. Live with it. We all do - or have to. Code first is even worse, in terms of large project usability.

It is seriously bad - but it is as it is. DevArt has a not too expensive alternative designer with a lot more capabilities (https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping model, open `YourModel.edmx` designer and select all tables, delete and update, right click and select `update model from database`.

Comment: Yeah. That totally helps keeping the charts and changes you did (like property renaming) around. Sadly bad.

Comment: I have to delete every single reference to the function and to its return value in the model.. it is very complex. Thanks anyway